# Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'View'

Tags: if-statement, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to put an `if` statement inside a NavigationLink using Xcode.

This is my code:

```
NavigationLink(destination: {

   if location.name == "Firm of the Future" {
       StartView()                   
   } else {
        Finish()
   }
}, label: {
    Text("Leer meer")
        .font(.headline)
        .frame(width: 125, height: 35)
})
```

With this code I'm getting the error:

> Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'View'

But when I use this code:

```
NavigationLink(destination: {
                
    if location.name == "Firm of the Future" {
        Text("Screen 1")                            
    } else {
        Text("Screen 2")
    }
}, label: {
    Text("Leer meer")
      .font(.headline)
      .frame(width: 125, height: 35)
})
```

it works.

What am I doing wrong in the first code?

This is the code for the views:
I'm using multiple bindings.

```
import SwiftUI

struct StartView: View {
    
    @State var Q1: String
    @State var Q2: String
    @State var Q3: String
    @State var Q4: String
    @State var Q5: String
    @State var Q6: String
    @State var Q7: String
    @State var Q8: String
    @State var theAnswer1: String
    @State var theAnswer2: String
    @State var theAnswer3: String
    @State var theAnswer4: String
    @State var theAnswer5: String
    @State var theAnswer6: String
    @State var theAnswer7: String
    @State var theAnswer8: String
    @State var AnsBool1: Bool
    @State var AnsBool2: Bool
    @State var AnsBool3: Bool
    @State var AnsBool4: Bool
    @State var AnsBool5: Bool
    @State var AnsBool6: Bool
    @State var AnsBool7: Bool
    @State var AnsBool8: Bool
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
        Image("WolvenBack")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            Image("FEClogokleur")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70, alignment: .leading)
                .position(x: 370, y: -70)
                
                
               
            
            
            VStack{
                
                Spacer()
              
                
                Text("De klim naar")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                    
                Text("het Wolvennest")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                    Spacer()
                    
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: FietsStap1(Q1: $Q1, Q2: Q2, Q3: Q3, Q4: Q4, Q5: Q5, Q6: Q6, Q7: Q7, Q8: Q8, theAnswer1: $theAnswer1, theAnswer2: $theAnswer2, theAnswer3: $theAnswer3, theAnswer4: $theAnswer4, theAnswer5: $theAnswer5, theAnswer6: $theAnswer6, theAnswer7: $theAnswer7, theAnswer8: $theAnswer8, AnsBool1: $AnsBool1, AnsBool2: $AnsBool2, AnsBool3: $AnsBool3,AnsBool4: $AnsBool4, AnsBool5: $AnsBool5, AnsBool6: $AnsBool6,AnsBool7: $AnsBool7,AnsBool8: $AnsBool8),
                
                    label: {
                Circle()
                            .fill(Color(red: 0.739, green: 0.818, blue: 0.022))
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 200, alignment: .bottom)
                    .padding(10)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                    .overlay(
                        Text("Start")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            
                    )}
                )}
                    
                }
                
                
            }
        }
    





struct StartView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var Q1 = String().self
    @State static var Q2 = String().self
    @State static var Q3 = String().self
    @State static var Q4 = String().self
    @State static var Q5 = String().self
    @State static var Q6 = String().self
    @State static var Q7 = String().self
    @State static var Q8 = String().self
    @State static var theAnswer1 = String().self
    @State static var theAnswer2 = String().self
    @State static var theAnswer3 = String().self
    @State static var theAnswer4 = String().self
    @State static var theAnswer5 = String().self
    @State static var theAnswer6 = String().self
    @State static var theAnswer7 = String().self
    @State static var theAnswer8 = String().self
    @State static var AnsBool1 = Bool().self
    @State static var AnsBool2 = Bool().self
    @State static var AnsBool3 = Bool().self
    @State static var AnsBool4 = Bool().self
    @State static var AnsBool5 = Bool().self
    @State static var AnsBool6 = Bool().self
    @State static var AnsBool7 = Bool().self
    @State static var AnsBool8 = Bool().self
    
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            NavigationView {
                StartView(Q1: Q1, Q2: Q2, Q3: Q3, Q4: Q4, Q5: Q5, Q6: Q6, Q7: Q7, Q8: Q8, theAnswer1: theAnswer1, theAnswer2: theAnswer2, theAnswer3: theAnswer3, theAnswer4: theAnswer4, theAnswer5: theAnswer5, theAnswer6: theAnswer6, theAnswer7: theAnswer7, theAnswer8: theAnswer8, AnsBool1: AnsBool1, AnsBool2:AnsBool2,AnsBool3: AnsBool3,AnsBool4: AnsBool4, AnsBool5: AnsBool5, AnsBool6: AnsBool6,AnsBool7: AnsBool7,AnsBool8: AnsBool8)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finish View

```
import SwiftUI

struct Finish: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Image("WolvenBack")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)

            Image("FEClogokleur")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70, alignment: .leading)
                .position(x: 410, y: 40)
                
            
           
            VStack{
                Text("")
                    .padding(.bottom, 140)
                
                ScrollView {
                Text("Gefeliciteerd! Je hebt de puzzel opgelost.")
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.vertical,10)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                
                Text("Je bent nu expert op het gebied van de wolf!")
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
              
                Image("Trophy")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
               
                    
            }
            }
        }
        }
}
struct Finish_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Finish()`?

Comment: Finish() is another view.

Comment: it looks like your "views" `StartView` and `Finish` return commands ... show us the code.

Comment: I edited my post. You can now see the code for StartView and Finish (View)

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, your `if` statement can return either a `StartView` or a `Finish`. The trouble is that the `destination:` block has to return a **concrete type** - that is, always the same type of object that conforms to the `View` protocol. The second example works because whatever path through the `if` statement is taken, it will always return a `Text` view.

The good news is that you can wrap your `if` statement in a `Group` – a semantically neutral view that can contain multiple types of view, but will wrap them in such a way that `destination` always receives the same type of view:

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: {
  Group {
    if location.name == "Firm of the Future" {
       StartView()                   
    } else {
       Finish()
    }
  }
}, label: {
    Text("Leer meer")
        .font(.headline)
        .frame(width: 125, height: 35)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick response! The error now changes to: Type '() -> Group<EmptyCommands>' cannot conform to 'View' - Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'CommandsBuilder'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not initialising all the `@State` variables of `StartView()`. You have 24 variables not initialised and no `init()`.

XCode always has a hard time processing Views when they are just a little bit complicated, so you see an error in the `NavigationLink` because it can't process its contents.

Either you put a default value on each variable, like `@State var Q1: String = ""`, or you create an `init() { }`, but then you'll have to provide the values in your call to `StartView(Q1: "Hello, Q2: "World", ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Finish` is a view... You need to provide a single view for navigation link instead of closure, so most simple fix is to use Group, like

```
NavigationLink(destination: Group {       // << here !!
                
                            if location.name == "Firm of the Future" {
                   StartView()
                                
                            } else {
                    Finish()
                            }
            }, label: {
                Text("Leer meer")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(width: 125, height: 35)
            })
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. When I do what you give me the following error occures: Generic struct 'NavigationLink' requires that 'EmptyCommands' conform to 'View' - Initializer 'init(destination:label:)' requires that 'EmptyCommands' conform to 'View' - Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'CommandsBuilder'

Comment: Most probably it is in some different code or you did something wrong when copied/adapted